# Remove function of the list removes value from every list present python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Python removes list value x from list1 as you can see below from the code :

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'x']
list2 = list1
#Remove value 'x' from list2
list2.remove('x')

#print list1
list1
['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a']
```

Comment: TL;DR: change line #2 to `list2 = list(list1)`

Comment: Thanks for the information. i have different type of list:
import copy
>>> list1 = [['a',1],['b',1],['c',2]]
>>> list2 = copy.copy(list1)
>>> list2
[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['c', 2]]
>>> list1
[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['c', 2]]
>>> list2.remove(['a',1])
>>> list1
[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['c', 2]]
>>> list2
[['b', 1], ['c', 2]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`list2 = list1` it is not a copy. list2 has only references to list1. 
 Use `deepcopy`, if the list  to copy contains compound objects, 
 or use list2 = list(list1) for non compound objects.


# use deep copy if the list contains compound objects
from copy import deepcopy
list2 = deepcopy(list1)



list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'x']
list2 = list1

list2 = deepcopy(list1)

list2.remove('x')

print(list1)

['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'x']
```